# send outlook email inside c++

Tags: c++, outlook, email

I'm witting a c++ program and need to generate an email inside of a c++ program to be sent to outlook.
The code im trying to use so far is something like this

```
system("cmd /c OUTLOOK.EXE /c ipm.note /m \"firstmail@mail.com&cc=ccmail@mail.com&subject=\"TestEmail\"&body=Hello%20World\"");
```

When I run this it will generate the email and fill in the TO field but not CC, subject, or body.
Rather it says it does not recognize these fields

Also does any one know how I can pass these in as a String into the function?

Thank You

Comment: That's not a function. It's a function CALL. You're just calling outlook via command-line arguments. And there appears to be no command-line args to specify an email's body via the CLI. http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/outlook-help/command-line-switches-HP001003110.aspx  maybe `/f` to load a .msg file

Comment: Do you know of a similar call or function that can accomplish this?

Comment: MS Office is a whole whack of programming apis, to the point that office is more an api, of which word/excel/outlook happen to be specific implementations/front-ends. There'll be apis to hook into Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like your flaw is the lack of a '?' before "subject" according to: http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;181991

```
const string to{"firstmail@mail.com"};
const string cc{"ccmail@mail.com"};
const string subject{"TestEmail"};
const string body{"Hello%20World"};
const string test{"cmd /c OUTLOOK.EXE /c ipm.note /m \"" + to + "&cc=" + cc + "?subject=" + subject + "&body=" +  body + '"'};

cout << test;
system(test);
```

As a temporary change to your code you can add `test`. That'll print you out a string. Navigate to the location of OUTLOOK.exe in a command prompt (mine is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14). Then enter the `std::string test` that got printed out, removing the "cmd /c" prefix, that should run. If not adjust as necessary in the command as necessary in the command prompt then adjust your code accordingly. My command for example looks like this:

> OUTLOOK.exe /c ipm.note /m "firstmail@mail.com&cc=ccmail@mail.com?subject=TestEmail&body=Hello%20World"

Comment: Thanks, it will allow me to pass in the address as a string now, but im still geting this. ***  .                                                    'cc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'subject' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'body' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Lightning77 I edited my answer hopefully that will get you started.